# Buscar arquivo e exibir o conteúdo

Tags: php

Preciso pegar um `arquivo.txt`, imprimí-lo na tela e informar o total de linhas, mas gostaria de "buscar" o arquivo em qualquer diretório do sistema

```
<?php

$arquivo = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'r');

while (!feof ($arquivo)) {
  $linha = fgets($arquivo);
  echo $linha."<br>";
}
fclose ($arquivo);

$linhas = count( file('arquivo.txt' ) );

echo "<br />Quantidade de linhas : ".$linhas;

?>
```

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? Seu código está funcionando?

Comment: Não, ele trava o navegador...

Comment: E dessa forma que fiz o arquivo.txt já está dentro da mesma pasta do arquivo.php, gostaria de, por exemplo, um campo que busque esse arquivo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para buscar todos os arquivos chamados `arquivo.txt` em qualquer sub-diretório a partir da raiz da aplicação, você pode utilizar a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php):

```
$files = glob("./**/*/arquivo.txt");
```

Neste caso, `$files` será uma lista com todos os arquivos de nome `arquivo.txt` em qualquer sub-diretório. Para exibir o conteúdo de cada um, assim como o número de linhas, basta fazer:

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $lines = substr_count($content, "\n");

    echo "Conteúdo: ", $content, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Linhas: ", $lines, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Considerando que você possua a seguinte estrutura de arquivos:

```
index.php
/foo
   /bar
      arquivo.txt
```

Sendo que o conteúdo do `arquivo.txt` é supostamente:

```
Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. 
Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. 
Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. 
Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. 
Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. 
Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. 
Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. 
Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. 
Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
```

A saída do programa será:

```
Conteúdo: Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. 
Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. 
Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. 
Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. 
Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. 
Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. 
Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. 
Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. 
Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
Linhas: 9
```